Is my controller broken or does Paper Mario naturally move up and down slowly?
I'm playing paper Mario on Wii Virtual console and when I move him up and down he's slow, moving right and left, as well as diagonals he moves just fine, and when I play Mario 64 on the same Wii and controller he moves just fine. I'm using a GameCube controller that looks lose in the down direction for context. Is that intended behavior?

Knowing Nintendo, no, this shouldn't happen.
I have many controllers that are loose in the knob as well, and they are way too sensitive (or not sensitive enough). I think you are just going to need to buy a new controller.

The fact about Super Mario 64. I believe if you move the knob just slightly, the Wii Virtual machine will treat it like you are moving your knob all the way. Probably an issue in how the emulator captures the controller inputs.
I never played GameCube and N64 on the Wii, so I could be wrong. I just know that things like this often happen.
